# Creating a dataframe with months x years based on time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series data with number of days for each month for several years and trying to create a new dataframe which would have months as rows and years as columns.

I have this

```
    DateTime    Days    Month   Year
        
    2004-11-30  3   November    2004
    2004-12-31  16  December    2004
    2005-01-31  12  January     2005
    2005-02-28  11  February    2005
    2005-03-31  11  March       2005
    ... ... ... ...
    2019-06-30  0   June        2019
    2019-07-31  2   July        2019
    2019-08-31  5   August      2019
    2019-09-30  5   September   2019
    2019-10-31  3   October     2019
```

And I'm trying to get this

```
Month     2004  2005 ... 2019

January   nan   12       7
February  nan   11       9
...
November  17    17       nan
December  14    15       nan
```

I created a new dataframe with the first column meaning months and tried to iterate through the first dataframe to add the new columns (years) and information to the cells but the condition which checks whether the month in the first dataframe (days) matches the month in the new dataframe (output) is never True, so the new dataframe never gets updated. I guess this is because the month in days is never the same as the month in output within the same iteration.

```
for index, row in days.iterrows():
print(days.loc[index, 'Days'])    #this prints out as expected
for month in output.items():
    print(index.month_name())     #this prints out as expected
    if index.month_name()==month:
        output.at[month, index.year]=days.loc[index, 'Days']    #I wanted to use this to fill up the cells, is this right?
        print(days.loc[index, 'Days'])      #this never gets printed out
```

Could you tell me how to fix this? Or maybe there's a better way to accomplish the result rather than iteration?
It's my first attempt to use libraries in python, so I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot), if your input dataframe has a single value per month and year:

```
df.pivot('Month', 'Year', 'Days')
```

Output:

```
Year      2004 2005 2019
Month                   
August     NaN  NaN    5
December    16  NaN  NaN
February   NaN   11  NaN
January    NaN   12  NaN
July       NaN  NaN    2
June       NaN  NaN    0
March      NaN   11  NaN
November     3  NaN  NaN
October    NaN  NaN    3
September  NaN  NaN    5
```